# SQL Query to sellect fallback option

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario.  I have the following MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
`ciso` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AUS',
`page` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
`dgroup` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0, 
UNIQUE KEY `page` (`page`,`ciso`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Typically it will have entries for multiple pages with ciso = 'AUS'.  In some instances there will be an override entry specific to the US where the page name will be the same as for the AUS entry but with ciso = 'USA'.

What I need to do from time-to-time is this - select all page entries with a specified dgroup setting & ciso = 'USA' by preference but if no such entry exists fall back to the matching AUS entry instead.  To make that a bit clearer

```
page   ciso  dgroup

PgA    AUS    3
PgB    AUS    3
PgC    AUS    3
PgD    AUS    4
PgB    USA    3
PgC    USA    3
```

In this instance the query, for dgroup = 3, should return PgA:AUS, PgB:USA and PgC:USA.

I can handle all of this with a spot of PHP but I suspect that it is possible to write a smart bit of SQL that does the job.  Only, I am just not that smart when it comes to SQL.  Perhaps someone here could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I've really understand what you're searching for but according to your result, I think this query would do;

```
SELECT page, ciso, dgroup
FROM   pages
Where  (ciso = 'USA' OR ciso = 'AUS')
AND     dgroup = 3
```

where you can specify the `dgroup`

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  I only do pretty basic SQL but even so I had a bit of a Homer Simson moment when I read your answer - why ever did I not think of OR!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT page, last(ciso) as last FROM `pages` where dgroup=3 group by page
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't think it helps.  My fault I guess - perhaps my question was not too clear.